# Add SKU column to Best Sellers Report

Tags: reports

I need to be able to add an SKU column to the Best Sellers report. I have managed to add the column to the page by adding:

```
$this->addColumn('sku', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Skus'),
            'width'     => '100px',
            'index'     => 'skus',
            'type'      => 'text',
        ));
```

to the `_prepareColumns()` function but I cannot work out where I need to select the SKUs from in the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Bestsellers` class.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Added this join to _prepareColumns but still not getting any data:

`$resourceCollection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->getResourceCollectionName());
$resourceCollection->join('catalog/product', 'product_id = entity_id', '*');

 $resourceCollection->setPeriod($filterData->getData('period_type'));
        $resourceCollection->setDateRange($filterData->getData('from', null), $filterData->getData('to', null));
        $resourceCollection->addStoreFilter($storeIds);
        $resourceCollection->setAggregatedColumns($this->_getAggregatedColumns());`

Answer (score 2):

What you will want to do is extend the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Sales_Bestsellers_Grid

Look at that class'es _prepareCollection() method

In your extended class, copy in the _prepareCollection() method, so you have a duplicate of it. Then modify it so that you are joining the product data against the collection.

```
$resourceCollection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->getResourceCollectionName()); 
$resourceCollection->join('catalog/product', 'product_id = entity_id', '*')
..
```

This should give you into your collection sku, and a number of other product information which you may wish to refine since we're selecting * in this case.

Now you need your column to reference the new columns which have been selected:

`$this->addColumn('sku', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Skus'),
            'width'     => '100px',
            'index'     => 'sku',
            'type'      => 'text',
        ));`

Note the lack of plural on sku (not skus).

This should now render with your grid showing SKU as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will write a module and try this out. I'm guessing the process will be the same for the other reports?

Comment: It should be yes. Provided that the collection in use has entity_id as a column representing the product. I should expect all the product focused ones will have this.

Comment: Hi John, just looking into this now and there doesn't seem to be a _prepareCollection() function in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Sales_Bestsellers_Grid. There is only _prepareColumns().

Comment: _prepareCollection is inherited from the parent class, Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Abstract. By putting this within your class you are overriding the functionality to provide your custom collection loading.

Comment: Ah yeah just checked that now. Knew it would be something like that. So I really only need to add the join condition to the existing $resourceCollection object?

Comment: Just tried to set this up but the join doesn't seem to be making any difference. Adding the column creates the Skus column in the grid but there is still no data being added to the Skus column.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very late answer. However, I will provide the way how I added the SKU into bestseller report grid in `Magento Open Source 2.3.4`

Assumptions: Custom module's namespace is `Apple` and the module name is `Custom`

> 01). Override the block
> `Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Bestsellers\Grid` In your
> custom module's `app/code/Apple/Custom/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Bestsellers\Grid" type="Apple\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Bestsellers\Grid" />
</config>
```

> 02). Now create the block file
> `app/code/Apple/Custom/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Bestsellers/Grid.php`

```
<?php

namespace Apple\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Bestsellers;


class Grid extends \Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Bestsellers\Grid
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory $resourceFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\Grouped\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Helper\Data $reportsData,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $resourceFactory, $collectionFactory, $reportsData, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getResourceCollectionName()
    {
        return \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection::class;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'period',
            [
                'header' => __('Interval'),
                'index' => 'period',
                'sortable' => false,
                'period_type' => $this->getPeriodType(),
                'renderer' => \Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Grid\Column\Renderer\Date::class,
                'totals_label' => __('Total'),
                'html_decorators' => ['nobr'],
                'header_css_class' => 'col-period',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-period'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'product_name',
            [
                'header' => __('Product'),
                'index' => 'product_name',
                'type' => 'string',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-product',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-product'
            ]
        );

        // add SKU
        $this->addColumnAfter(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('SKU'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'renderer' => \Apple\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\Renderer\Sku::class,
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sku',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sku'
            ],
            'period'
        );

        if ($this->getFilterData()->getStoreIds()) {
            $this->setStoreIds(explode(',', $this->getFilterData()->getStoreIds()));
        }
        $currencyCode = $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

        $this->addColumn(
            'product_price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
                'index' => 'product_price',
                'sortable' => false,
                'rate' => $this->getRate($currencyCode),
                'header_css_class' => 'col-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-price'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'qty_ordered',
            [
                'header' => __('Order Quantity'),
                'index' => 'qty_ordered',
                'type' => 'number',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-qty',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-qty'
            ]
        );

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportBestsellersCsv', __('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportBestsellersExcel', __('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

> 03). Now create the renderer class for our custom column `SKU` in
> `app/code/Apple/Custom/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Column/Renderer/Sku.php`

```
<?php

namespace Apple\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\Renderer;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Context;

class Sku extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    /**
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productloader;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ProductFactory $productloader
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ProductFactory $productloader,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->productloader = $productloader;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param DataObject $row
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        $id = (int)$row->getProductId();
        $product = $this->productloader->create()->load($id);
        return $product->getSku();
    }
}
```

> 4. Run below commands from your Magento root directory

```
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

> Once you login to Magento admin you should see the new SKU column in
> bestseller grid as shown below.

[image]